# Conceptual Difference: Fully Abstract Class v. Interface

Tags: java, class, interface, abstraction

I am wondering if I have the correct understanding of the theoretical difference between a fully abstract class and an interface. I understand the technical differences.

My understanding is that classes are used for concrete objects and interfaces for features those objects can exhibit. So If I was making a car class, and I wanted that car to have a navigation feature, I would make a navigation interface rather than an abstract class correct? (Replace with any feature, i.e. automatic parking, etc)

Comment: Since this topic is off-topic, I will post a short answer here instead. The conceptual difference: a class specifies the properties of an entity (often identified as a noun, such a "Person","Car" etc.). An interface specifies the behaviors of a TYPE of entity. A fully abstract class has to make assumptions about its child types - all subclasses will all inherit the same properties, and (by definition) are still the same entity (a Car, Truck, Motorbike are still Vehicles). Interfaces make no such assumption about properties; they merely define what a type of entity (Drivable) can do.

Comment: thanks daryl that helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theoretical difference between the two is off-topic here, you might want to ask at http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

The closest on-topic question for so is what you can do with them, which you probably already know -- a `class` can `implement` two `interfaces`, it can `extend` only one `class`.

Comment: That's only true if the programming language does not support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

A boat or a plane could also have an automatic parking feature or a navigation system.
But in most models, something is either a boat or a car (let's leave flying cars out...).

Practically, in Java an abstract class is a good way to force an extension in a particular (unique) category. If you have AbstractPlane and AbstractBoat, you are sure an object is either one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Fully abstract class is very similar to interface, practically identical. When it comes to particular languages, differences arises. For example, in Java class can extend only one other class but can implement many interfaces.

Regarding your example is correct. Class is collection of 2 main things: data and methods to work with that data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track. Think of it this way. You have a fruit. But you don't know which one it might be. So you make an interface fruit which is upto the user now how may they use this interface. It might be apple, oranges or peach. The interface fruit will have a definite size, color and environment it grows. Though this information changes according to different types of fruits.

In other words, interface is like a skeleton of something very very specific that you are trying to accomplish in the long run.